Identify animated series about postapocalyptic Earth
I've been looking for an animated series that I saw on a TV about 10 years ago.
Here is what I remember about it:

the main character is a teenager
he is carrying some kind of robot which is very important and will help him save humanity. The robot looks like a mace and it can be plugged into ports on old hardware and significantly improve its performance.
I also remember that closer to the end of the series there were a mech where this robot was inserted, so it looked like the robot become a head of this thing.
people (part of them) are afraid of the sunlight, but they aren't vampires.
those who are afraid of the sunlight are leaving underground.


Sounds very much like an Anime series. Was it in English or dubbed over?

@DustinDavis it was dubbed and I am sure that it wasn't anime.

@DustinDavis but I'm Russian, so I think original language was English.


Xyber 9: New Dawn

Terrana once was a utopia of technological advances and living in
  peace, but that age ended long ago. Amid the ruins, King Renard pushed
  his troops out and all over the land, while Queen Tatania tries her
  hardest to win her country back. King Renard is too powerful, because
  he is an ally of Machestro, an evil lord of the underworld thought
  only to exist in myth.



Jack, The Chosen One and a 15-year-old orphan, is called upon by the
  people of Terrana. In order to become king, he needs to kill
  Machestro. Jack's greatest weapon against Machestro is the
  sophisticated computer Xyber 9 that is in the form of a staff.



With Xyber 9's power, Jack journeys through Machestro's underworld and
  to other futuristic lands, fighting intergalactic evil with an ever
  increasing band of allies.

Here's a description of the people living underground:

It is also revealed that Machestro rules over the Machina by giving
  them hope that they will be able to reclaim the surface by turning it
  dark. This is because the Machina have a virus that causes them to be
  in great pain when traveling into the sunlight.

~ Series info from Wikipedia; Images from KinoPoisk and tvtropes
For more details go here. Watch the first episode here or here.

It sounds like Gurren Lagann (Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann). It is from 2007 though.
Plot summary from imdb:

In a bleak future where humanity is oppressed by an army of mutants and forced to live underground, a young orphan unearths a powerful robot. Together with a boisterous man named Kamina, a beautiful sharpshooter named Yoko and many other friends, they use the robots power to fight against their oppressors and take back the surface. 

The series involve:

Teenager main character 
An important robot that will save the world (with the help of other robots) 
People living underground
Small mecha becomes the head of a big mecha


Other candidates would be:

Mazinger Series
Neon Genesis Evangelion

